# More Efficient Nav Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I just need to know if there is a more efficient way of writing this block of code for transition effects on my navigation menu.  It's using ajax transitions if you're wondering why I don't just apply each class individually.

here's the javascript code:

```
var navA = $('#nav a'),
    aboutBtn = $('#aboutBtn'),
    portfolioBtn = $('#portfolioBtn'),
    resumeBtn = $('#resumeBtn'),
    photoBtn = $('#photoBtn');

navA.on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    // if the resumeBtn is clicked
    if ($this.attr('id') == 'resumeBtn') {

        // Portfolio
        portfolioBtn.removeClass('portfolioActive');
        portfolioBtn.addClass('portfolio');

        //About Me
        aboutBtn.removeClass('aboutActive');
        aboutBtn.addClass('about');

        // Photo
        photoBtn.removeClass('photoActive');
        photoBtn.addClass('photo');

        // Resume
        resumeBtn.removeClass('resume');
        resumeBtn.addClass('resumeActive');
    }
    // If portfolioBtn Is Clicked
    else if ($this.attr('id') == 'portfolioBtn') {

        // About
        aboutBtn.removeClass('aboutActive');
        aboutBtn.addClass('about');

        // Resmue
        resumeBtn.removeClass('resumeActive');
        resumeBtn.addClass('resume');

        // Photo
        photoBtn.removeClass('photoActive');
        photoBtn.addClass('photo');

        // Portfolio
        portfolioBtn.removeClass('portfolio');
        portfolioBtn.addClass('portfolioActive');
    }
    // If photoBtn Is Clicked
    else if($this.attr('id') == 'photoBtn') {

        // About
        aboutBtn.removeClass('aboutActive');
        aboutBtn.addClass('about');

        // Portfolio
        portfolioBtn.removeClass('portfolioActive');
        portfolioBtn.addClass('portfolio');

        // Resume
        resumeBtn.removeClass('resumeActive');
        resumeBtn.addClass('resume');

        // Photo
        photoBtn.removeClass('photo');
        photoBtn.addClass('photoActive');
    } 
    // If aboutBtn is clicked
    else if ($this.attr('id') == 'aboutBtn') {

        // Portfolio
        portfolioBtn.removeClass('portfolioActive');
        portfolioBtn.addClass('portfolio');

        // About Me
        aboutBtn.removeClass('about');
        aboutBtn.addClass('aboutActive');

        // Resume
        resumeBtn.removeClass('resumeActive');
        resumeBtn.addClass('resume');
        // Photo
        photoBtn.removeClass('photoActive');
        photoBtn.addClass('photo');
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a class="resume" href="resume.html" id="resumeBtn">Resume</a>
    <a class="portfolio" href="portfolio.html" id="portfolioBtn">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="photo" href="photos2.html" id="photoBtn">Photos</a>
    <a class="aboutActive" href="index.html" id="aboutBtn">About Me</a>
</div>
```

The CSS classes uses images for the transitions, but either way. I just wanna know if there's a more efficient way to write my jQuery. I'm sure there is I'm just having a stupid moment. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm structuring the code differently in how it handles the panel switches and this section of code is just designed to handle the Nav transitions.

So essentially, I removed the bottom of each`IF`statement so it only handles the the nav transitions.

Comment: Are the classes like portfolioActive, aboutActive, etc the same?

Comment: You don't need the `$this` variable, because the only thing you've used it for is to check `$this.attr('id')` and that can be replaced with the more efficient `this.id`.

Comment: You could do all the `removeClass` calls in one go and then only do a conditional `addClass`, but that's just making the code smaller and easier to read.  Won't improve efficiency at runtime.  Also a switch statement would be easier to read than a lot if if/if else statements.

Comment: What are "ajax transitions"? I've never heard of this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your panels have the same HTML structure as your navs, this will work:

```
$('#nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Buttons
    $('#' + this.id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    // Panels    
    $('#' + this.id.slice(0, this.id.lastIndexOf('Btn')) + 'Panel').show().siblings().hide();

    notworkOn = false;
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'portfolioBtn':
            handlePortfolio();
            break;
        case 'aboutBtn':
            handleAbout();
            break;
    }
});

function handlePortfolio() { arrange(); }
function handleAbout() {
    arrange();
    $('#header .inner').animate({ width: '100%' }, 600);
}
```

That assumes your panels HTML structure is similar to your Buttons, and named `resumePanel` etc. Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/9vwYm/1/

**Edit:** Your current code seems to have some inconsistencies in it, e.g. clicking the *Photo* button displays the Photo panel, and then when you click on *About*, the Photo panel is not hidden. Is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry no it's not intentional I must have just overlooked it. Those chunks of code are going to be removed because I'm going to structure the code differently.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy, but twice as short and wo/ repetitive error-prone parts.

```
var pages = [
    {   title: 'about',
        showPanel: aboutPanel,
        dontHidePanels: [photoPanel, resumePanel],
        extracode: function() {
            notworkOn = false;
            arrange();
            $('#header .inner').animate({ 
                width: '100%'
            }, 600);
        }
    }, 
    {   title: 'protfolio',
        showPanel: horizon,
        dontHidePanels: [resumePanel],
        extracode: function() {
            arrange()
            notworkOn = false;
        }
    }, 
    {   title: 'resume',
        showPanel: resumePanel,
        dontHidePanels: [servicesPanel],
        extracode: function() {
            notworkOn = false;
        }
    }, 
    {   title: 'photo',
        showPanel: photoPanel,
        dontHidePanels: [resumePanel],
        extracode: function() {
            notworkOn = false;
        }
    }
];

var panels = [  aboutPanel, horizon, photoPanel, resumePanel, servicesPanel];

$('#nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var curPageTitle = this.id.match(/(\w+)Btn/)[1];
    var p = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        if (pages[i].title == curPageTitle) {
            $('#' + pages[i].title + 'Btn')
                .removeClass(pages[i].title + 'Active')
                .addClass(pages[i].title);
            p = pages[i];
        } else {
            $('#' + pages[i].title + 'Btn')
                .removeClass(pages[i].title)
                .addClass(pages[i].title + 'Active');
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; p++) {
        if (panels[i] == p.showPanel) {
            panels[i].css('display', 'block');
        } else if ($.inArray(panels[i], p.dontHidePanels) != -1) {
            panels[i].css('display','none');
        }
    }
    p.extracode();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your class structure to use a separate `active` class:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a class="resume" href="resume.html" id="resumeBtn">Resume</a>
    <a class="portfolio" href="portfolio.html" id="portfolioBtn">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="photo" href="photos2.html" id="photoBtn">Photos</a>
    <a class="about active" href="index.html" id="aboutBtn">About Me</a>
</div>
```

And then do this with the script (**EDIT** missed the fact that your header animation was only for the about, so changed that below):

```
$('#nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    //Toggle active
    $this.parent().find('.active').toggleClass('active');
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    //Hide All Panals
    horizon.css('display','none');
    aboutPanel.css('display','none');
    photoPanel.css('display', 'none');
    resumePanel.css('display', 'none');

    //Show Correct Panel
    switch($this.id){
     case 'resumeBtn':
       resumePanel.css('display', 'block');
     break;
     case 'portfolioBtn':
       horizon.css('display','block');
     break;
     case 'photoBtn':
       photoPanel.css('display','block');
       arrange();
     break;
    case 'aboutBtn':
       aboutPanel.css('display','block');
       arrange();
       $('#header .inner').animate({ 
            width: '100%'
       },600);
    break;
   }
   notworkOn = false;

    };
});
```

Comment: You're assuming Active is a separate class but it's not. I'm working with an image sprite the text theoretically never appears.  This would work fine with the panel switches but would do nothing for the actual nav transitions.

Comment: @Wild_Fire126--actually, I was not assuming `active` was a separate class, I was suggesting making it so to reduce the code. It appears the answer you accepted (Josh Hah) also coded based of a separate `active` class. For nav transitions, what you had codes as `.aboutActive`, I would have coded `.about.active` to allow for the separate class. But I'm glad you found one of the solutions here to your benefit.

Comment: I ended up changing his code bit, but his seemed the most simple in the long run.